# Opening instagram authentication webpage in kivy/kivyMd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Hello please I’m trying to open the instagram authentication webpage url in my kivy app to enable users login with instagram
I’ve used requests and urlrequest but it doesn’t open the page
I’ve installed webview but couldn’t find a good documentation on how to use it and how to pass the instagram app id and secret
So i can get the token
Please is there any other way to do this
Please help me out
I’d appreciate a guide and probably a code snippet
And sorry I haven’t done any
code with the webview
‘’’ import requests

```
req = requests.get(auth url, params)
```

‘’’

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thats the only code i've used

Comment: i used the requests module i was hoping to open the login page and once login is complete then return to my app is there help you can offer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819842/how-can-i-login-in-instagram-with-python-requests